# MySql: Advanced sorting 1st row to highest then lowest to highest?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I need my result set like this:

```
First  Last  Amount
Bob    Nolan 789
Bob    Nolan 0
Bob    Nolan 23
Bob    Nolan 55
Mavis  Li    3030
Mavis  Li    0
Mavis  Li    213
Mavis  Li    449
```

The first record of the person should always give me the highest amount then the second and so forth should give me from the lowest to highest.

How would I sort this?

Thanks

Comment: what if you have 2 records with same max value? for example 2 records with `Bob    Nolan 789`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirements? I don't understand how all the Bob Nolans are sorted.

Comment: Hi @alex that wouldn't be possible in our system.  The First Record of the person is actually their gross wages.  The 2nd and so on is actually the taxes they are paying from those gross wages.

First Record of the person would always have the highest max value.  second, third, forth, fifth record of the person would always go from lowest to highest.

Comment: Do you have something that you can add to the result set that identifies the gross wages record?

Comment: perfect, so what is your problem then? if you know what is your data in fufture - what is your question about then?

Comment: Hi @mureonik, i actually want the resultset sorted like the one on the top.  I haven't found a way to do so.  This is data would actually be exported and imported to another payrolling system.

Comment: I guess your next question on SO would be: *How to return exactly 4 rows per username*

Comment: By the way, I have huge experience with accounting system development, and you could be surprised that in some cases wage amount could be smaller then tax amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> The First Record of the person is actually their gross wages. The 2nd
>   and so on is actually the taxes they are paying from those gross
>   wages.

Why not add a column for the type of transaction and then use that column in your sort?

**Update - dedicated to Alex**

To make my answer more "answery", the query would be something like:

```
select * 
  from yourTable 
  order by 
    firstName, 
    lastName, 
    IF(transactionType='grossWages', 0, 1), 
    amount;
```

Comment: Even if I like your comment, it is still comment - not an answer, sorry pal :-)

Comment: You can believe it?  finally he picked your Answer (not a comment) :-)

Comment: sorry both of your answers were correct I can only pick one :(

Comment: You can do another thing - ask clearly what you are really need and post more details like: table schema, sample of raw data etc next time :-)

Comment: @Arth - I upvoted your answer as it answers the question as asked.  However, I still prefer this solution for performance reasons, especially if you have/could have a column that makes logical sense :)

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely cannot change the structure...

```
  SELECT t1.*
    FROM table t1
    JOIN (
      SELECT first, last, MAX(amount) max
        FROM table
    GROUP BY first, last
         ) t2
      ON t2.first = t1.first
     AND t2.last = t1.last
ORDER BY t1.first, 
         t2.last,
         t1.amount = t2.max DESC,
         t1.amount
```

I would seriously consider adding a column to show type of transaction.

As an aside.. the taxes are presumably negative transactions as well so a minus sign in front of these would allow you to `ORDER BY first, last, amount DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the table name accordingly.

```
select * from so_30240116 a where 
a.amount=(
select max(b.amount) from so_30240116 b 
where a.first=b.first and a.last=b.last group by b.first, b.last
)
union
select * from so_30240116 a where 
a.amount!=(
select max(b.amount) from so_30240116 b 
where a.first=b.first and a.last=b.last group by b.first, b.last
)
order by first,last
```